# How to display innerHtml in nextjs (having tailwind)

Tags: react-hooks, next.js, innerhtml, rich-text-editor, displaytag

I have generated a   rich-text using a ckedtor in laravel and fetched it to nextjs for display. I have used:

```
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
```

and:
ReactHtmlParser(htmlString) but
None outputs the texts as it appears in laravel backend, actually its missing the styling (i.e: bold, font-size, bulleting, link-color and numbering.
How can display this richtext in nextjs? Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with Tailwindcss, it overrides all the styles and resets them.

There is a plugin you can use to fix that. install it:

```
npm install -D @tailwindcss/typography
```

update your tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
       // ...
    },
    plugins: [
       require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
       // ...
    ],
}
```

then give `className="prose"` to your rich text editor div

for more information you can visit this [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin)

Comment: Thanks - this solved my problem which is slightly different. I import an mdx file and use its content as component in a next js web app. However, while the markdown formatting characters like ### and * etc. are not displayed as expected, apparently tailwind still prevents any styling. So the displayed html is without paragraphs, lists, larger, smaller fonts etc....

Comment: Glad it helped you! <3